# Populate SharePoint textfield value into dialog dropdown

Tags: 2007, jquery, spservices, aspx

Today i ran into this issue, simply described:

I have a SharePoint custom list where I have added a custom button in the it's ribbon, this button pops up a custom ASPX modal dialog, this dialog only contains an ASP dropdown and a button, se screenshot below:

[image]

What I'm willing to achieve is to retrieve all values of for example the "Title" list column, and populate those values into the dialog's dropdown. Se script below:

```
$(window).bind("load", function () {
    var container = new Array(),
        i = 0;
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        listName: "Project review",
        webUrl: "/internal/lists/project%20review",
        async: false,
        CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'></Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>" + "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" + "</ViewFields>",
        completefunc: function (xData, ID) {
            $(xData.responseXML).find('z\\:row, row').each(function () {
                container[i++] = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
                alert(container);
                for (var i = 0; i < container.length; i++) {
                    var opt = container[i];
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.textContent = opt;
                    option.value = opt;
                    var toDropDown = document.getElementById("managers_list");
                    toDropDown.appendChild(option);
                }
            });
        }
    });
})
```

The script does unfortunately not do my purpose, anyone who could shed some light upon this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try getting rid of the webUrl and CAMLQuery options. And depending on your version of spservices, you should be using SPFilterNode instead of .find.

Comment: Thanks! Your hints helped, I had also to use:
completefunc: function(xData, Status) {xData.responseXML} 

instead of:

completefunc: function(xData, ID) {xData.responseText}

in order to get it working. For the xData.responseXml i understand why, but not really why I had to use Status instead of ID, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        listName: "Project review",
        webUrl: "/internal/",
        async: false,
        CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Gt><FieldRef Name='Id'/><Value Type='Number'>0</Value></Gt></Where></Query>",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>" + "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" + "</ViewFields>",
        completefunc: function (xData, ID) {
            $(xData.responseXML).find('z\\:row, row').each(function () {
                $('#managers_list').append("<option>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</option>");
            });
        }
    });
});
```